# @ngtools/Webpack Module not found AOT

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, aot

I am trying to AOT compile my Angular + Webpack application and I have some issues with it, particularly with `lazy loading`

I am using the `@ngtools/Webpack` plugin and when the bundling starts, the bundling stops because it can't find a lazy loaded module; it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'/Users/xsd/workbench/compiled/node_modules/carbonldp-panel/my-apps/my-apps.module.ngfactory.ts' in '/Users/xsd/workbench/compiled/‘`
```

The LazyLoaded module is coming from another library called `carbonldp-panel` which is in node_modules and not inside the `src` of the project.

This project was not created using the `angular-cli` library, and because I've been stumbling upon many issues combining the plugin with angular-cli, this left me asking... Can the `@ngtools/Webpack` plugin be used with projects that don't have the `angular-cli`library?

And also, if I first run `ngc` to generate the missing library, and then bundle the project, the bundling continues ok, so this also left me asking, must I have to first `ngc` the project and then bundle it using the `@ngtools/webpack` with project without the `angular-cli` plugin or is the loader supposed to generate the missing factory files by itself?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ng2 or ng4? What version of ngtools/webpack? and can you post your webpack config?

Comment: Just tried now with ngtools 1.3.1 and it does not work.
I also tried 1.4.0 beta - it does not work also - but with different error